# Is there a Xamarin Bitbucket plugin

Tags: xamarin, bitbucket

Is there a plugin for Xamarin that will allow me to push my code to Bitbucket with ease (pushing it when I click a button)?

Comment: Xamarin Studio has built in support for Subversion and Git - BitBucket supports Git and Mercurial.  So using Git should work.

Comment: @Jason I think he means that he wants the code to not only be committed to the local git repository, but also synced up with remote git repository hosted on BitBucket.

Comment: I can't find out how to install ssh keys to get bitbucket authorization.....to the web!

Comment: It *should* work, but I keep getting Credentials required for the repository: ssh://git@bitbucket.org:22
Passphrase for /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/idrsa